# Performance issue persisting/Updating large list of objects using JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have one-many unidirectional mapping in 3 entities.

```java
class A {
    List<B> listB ;

    // getter setters
}

class B {
    List<C> listC:

    //getter Setter
}

class C {
  //fields 
}
```

Both the listB and listC having large no of objects. When I am persisting object A it persist B and C also.

only issue I am facing is performance. I am thinking about iterating over listB and persist in batch.

Is there any other option to persist large list ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using hibernate as JPA provider. Fine-tune your entity manager using options from:
    org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings
"search" using "batch" keyword, it may help.

Performance is a tricky topic - all depends on a business logic that you are implementing.